# Changing of Event not Happening

Tags: java, android

I built a TicTacToe game for Android. I want to show on screen whose turn is upcoming like  is it User's turn or Android's turn.
I built a function updateGameInfo for this which is working but i am not able to decide where should i call this function to get proper output on display.
Please Help Thanks in Advance.
Here's my Code

```
 public class Game extends Activity {
private final int GAME_VICTORY = 0x1;
private final int GAME_DEFEAT = 0x2;
private final int GAME_TIE = 0x3;
private final int GAME_CONTINUES = 0x4;
private final float UNIQUE_MAX_WEIGHT=0.85f;
static final int ACTIVITY_SELECTION = 1;
private int x_Player_win_counter;
private int o_Player_win_counter;
public static TextView textlevel=null;
public static TextView textlevel1=null;
public static TextView textlevel2=null;
public static TextView textlevel3=null;
public double userBest_Time=0;
public double cpuBest_Time=0;
public double startTime;
long prev_Time=0;
double userDuration;
double cpuDuration;
private float[] w;  
private int[] c;        
private int[][] PosTable;   
private Button[] buttons;
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.game);
    buttons = new Button[9];
    buttons[0] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
    buttons[0].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(0);
        }
    });
    buttons[1] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
    buttons[1].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(1);
        }
    });
    buttons[2] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button03);
    buttons[2].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(2);
        }
    });
    buttons[3] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button04);
    buttons[3].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(3);
        }
    });
    buttons[4] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button05);
    buttons[4].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(4);
        }
    });
    buttons[5] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button06);
    buttons[5].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(5);
        }

    });
    buttons[6] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button07);
    buttons[6].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(6);
        }
    });
    buttons[7] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button08);
    buttons[7].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(7);
        }
    });
    buttons[8] = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button09);
    buttons[8].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            btnClicked(8);
        }
    });

  startActivityForResult(new Intent(Game.this, Game.class), ACTIVITY_SELECTION);


    DisplayMetrics dm = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    float h = (float) (dm.heightPixels - (100.0)*dm.density);
    float w = dm.widthPixels;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        buttons[i].setHeight((int) (h/3));
        buttons[i].setWidth((int) (w/3));
    }
}
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    beginPlay();
    if (requestCode == ACTIVITY_SELECTION) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
            if (extras.getString("result").equals("CPU")) cpuPlay();
        }
    }
}
public void userGame() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("User Won!!!")
    .setMessage("want to start another game")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

            buttonsEnable(true);
            beginPlay();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .show();


}

public void cpuGame() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Android Won!!!")
    .setMessage("want to start another game")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

            buttonsEnable(true);
            beginPlay();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .show();


}

public void tieGame() {
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("TIE!!!")
    .setMessage("want to start another game")
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {

            buttonsEnable(true);
            beginPlay();
        }
    })
    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) 
        {
            finish();
        }
    })
    .show();


}


private void beginPlay() {
    //initializations start 
    w=new float[9];
    c=new int[9];
    InitTable();
    w[0]=0.7f;
    w[1]=0.4f;
    w[2]=0.7f;
    w[3]=0.4f;
    w[4]=0.7f;
    w[5]=0.4f;
    w[6]=0.7f;
    w[7]=0.4f;
    w[8]=0.7f;
    //c[i] : 0 for empty, 1 for cpu, 2 for user
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        c[i]=0;
    //initializations done

    //now we play!
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        textlevel=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.userInfo);
        textlevel.setText(String.valueOf(x_Player_win_counter));

        textlevel1=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.cpuInfo);
        textlevel1.setText(String.valueOf(o_Player_win_counter));
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        {     
        updateBtn(i);
        buttons[i].setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
        }
    String PlayerName="User";       
    updateGameInfo(PlayerName + " turn.");
}
private void cpuPlay() {
    //computer plays first
    int cpos=getDecision();
    if (cpos == -1) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GAME OVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        return;
    }
    c[cpos]=1;
    updateBtn(cpos);
    int gstatus = CheckGameStatus();
    if (gstatus == GAME_VICTORY) {
        userDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrts You Won in " + userDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        ++x_Player_win_counter;
        userGame();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_DEFEAT) {
        cpuDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Android Won in "  + cpuDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        ++o_Player_win_counter;
        cpuGame();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_TIE) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Its a TIE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
        tieGame();
    }
    else if (gstatus == GAME_CONTINUES) {
        //user plays
    }
}
private void updateBtn(int i) {
    if(c[i]==0)
        buttons[i].setText(" ");
    else if(c[i]==1)
        {
        String PlayerName="Android";        
        updateGameInfo(PlayerName + " turn.");
        try {
            Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        buttons[i].setText("O");
        buttons[i].setTextColor(Color.RED);

        }
    else
        {
        String PlayerName="User";       
        updateGameInfo(PlayerName + " turn.");
        buttons[i].setText("X");

        }
}
private int CheckGameStatus() {
    int s = 0;
    //check horizontal
    if(c[0]==2&&c[1]==2&&c[2]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[3]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[5]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[6]==2&&c[7]==2&&c[8]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[0]==1&&c[1]==1&&c[2]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[3]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[5]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[6]==1&&c[7]==1&&c[8]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    //check vertical
    if(c[0]==2&&c[3]==2&&c[6]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[1]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[7]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[2]==2&&c[5]==2&&c[8]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[0]==1&&c[3]==1&&c[6]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[1]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[7]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[2]==1&&c[5]==1&&c[8]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    //check diagonal
    if(c[0]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[8]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[2]==2&&c[4]==2&&c[6]==2) {s = GAME_VICTORY;}
    if(c[0]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[8]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}
    if(c[2]==1&&c[4]==1&&c[6]==1) {s = GAME_DEFEAT;}

    if (s != 0) {
        buttonsEnable(false);
        return s;
    }

    boolean box_empty = false;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++) {
        if (c[i] == 0) box_empty = true;
    }
    if (box_empty) {    //if any box is empty -> game continues
        return GAME_CONTINUES;
    }
    else {  //else there is tie
        buttonsEnable(false);
        return GAME_TIE;
    }
}

private void buttonsEnable(boolean b) {
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        buttons[i].setEnabled(b);
}

private void btnClicked(int i) {
    if(c[i]!=0) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position occupied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
    else {
        //all OK
        c[i] = 2;
        updateBtn(i);
        int gstatus = CheckGameStatus();
        if (gstatus == GAME_VICTORY) {
            userDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Congrats You Won in "  + userDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            ++x_Player_win_counter;
            userGame();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_DEFEAT) {
            cpuDuration = (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)/1000;
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry, Android Won in "  + cpuDuration + " seconds", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            ++o_Player_win_counter;
            cpuGame();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_TIE) {
            Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Its a TIE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            toast.show();
            tieGame();
        }
        else if (gstatus == GAME_CONTINUES) {
            cpuPlay();
        }
    }
}

private int getDecision() {
    String Player="Android";
//  updateGameInfo(Player + " turn.");
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++) {
            if(c[i]==1&&c[j]==1)    //place 'o' to win
                if(PosTable[i][j]!=-1)  //if we have 3 in a row
                    if(c[PosTable[i][j]]==0)    //if position is free
                        return PosTable[i][j];
            if(c[i]==2&&c[j]==2)    //place 'o' to prevent user's victory
                if(PosTable[i][j]!=-1)  //if we have 3 in a row
                    if(c[PosTable[i][j]]==0)    //if position is free
                        return PosTable[i][j];
        }

    if(c[0]==1&&c[8]==0) return 8;
    if(c[2]==1&&c[6]==0) return 6;
    if(c[8]==1&&c[0]==0) return 0;
    if(c[6]==1&&c[2]==0) return 2;
    Random r=new Random();
    boolean exist07=false;
    boolean[] free=new boolean[9]; //will hold the free positions
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        free[i]=false;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(c[i]==0) {   //free ??
            free[i]=true;   //add position to free
            if(w[i]==UNIQUE_MAX_WEIGHT) return i;
        }
    //more than 1 positions with same weight
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(free[i]) //if position is free
            if(w[i]==0.7f) exist07=true;
    if(exist07)
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            if(free[i]) //if position is free
                if(w[i]==0.4f) free[i]=false;

    int j=0;
    int rn=0;
    int[] tmp;
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        if(free[i]) j++;
    if(j!=0) {
        tmp=new int[j];
        rn=r.nextInt(j);
        j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
            if(free[i]) tmp[j++]=i;
        return tmp[rn];
    }
    else {
        return -1; //else GAME OVER
    }
}
private void InitTable() {

    PosTable=new int[9][9];
    for(int i=0;i<9;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<9;j++)
            PosTable[i][j]=-1;
    PosTable[0][1]=2;
    PosTable[0][2]=1;
    PosTable[0][3]=6;
    PosTable[0][4]=8;
    PosTable[0][6]=3;
    PosTable[0][8]=4;
    PosTable[1][2]=0;
    PosTable[1][4]=7;
    PosTable[1][7]=4;
    PosTable[2][4]=6;
    PosTable[2][5]=8;
    PosTable[2][6]=4;
    PosTable[2][8]=5;
    PosTable[3][4]=5;
    PosTable[3][5]=4;
    PosTable[3][6]=0;
    PosTable[4][5]=3;
    PosTable[4][6]=2;
    PosTable[4][7]=1;
    PosTable[4][8]=0;
    PosTable[5][8]=2;
    PosTable[6][7]=8;
    PosTable[6][8]=7;
    PosTable[7][8]=6;

}
private void updateGameInfo(String info)
{
    TextView infoView =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.gameInfo);
    infoView.setText(info);
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hey change your code of game_contiues in btnClicked

```
String name= "Android";
            updateGameInfo("Wait it's" + name + " turn");
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    cpuPlay();
                }
            },500);
```

This will surly sort out your problem

Answer (score 1):

I think you can put your updateGameInfo part after this..

```
      private void btnClicked(int i) {
    if(c[i]!=0) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Position occupied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
    toast.show();
}
else {
    //all OK
    c[i] = 2;
    updateBtn(i);
     updateGameInfo(Player + " turn.");<---every time you are updating the value on button call updategameinfo...
   ....
    //remaining code...
```

and also here..

```
       private void cpuPlay() {
   //computer plays first
   int cpos=getDecision();
    if (cpos == -1) {
    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GAME OVER", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
       toast.show();
    return;
    }
   c[cpos]=1;
    updateBtn(cpos);
     updateGameInfo(Player + " turn.");<-----
  //remaining code here...
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this is working actually but actually it happens so fast that computer don't get time to update that field. So i tried to implement sleep() method before cpuPlay() but it makes sleep to both mean user and android together and wake together so again computer is not getting time to update. Can u tell me how to use sleep() or do i need to use wait(). Thanks in Advance

Comment: You can just use sleep after this line..  updateGameInfo(Player + " turn.");<-----.. the last line in my answer... but if you sleep the thread for 1 sec here.. then after the cpu plays.. only after 1 second the user can play.. because the thread sleeps for that time and cannot take inputs like touch...

Comment: thanks again for help, it is not working by using sleep because it put both method for sleep because they both are running by same thread. But no problem because i have got the solution by using Handler

Comment: Okays here you go. BTW Thanks Again for help. Your contribution is really appreciated. But never forget i accepted your answer so don't  forget when it comes to you. ;) :)

Answer (score 1):

use Handler, wherever you want to hold the game and set the text